# Nodejs Firebase and Angular4 Authentication

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a client application, written in angular4 which communicates with a firebase server. Currently I'm trying to integrate a nodejs with firebase in a way that it will communicate with client app as well.

> Firebase <---->  Client (Angular4) <----> NodeJs(firebase-admin) <----> Firebase

I have setup a fire-admin configs:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./server/myfile.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://mydb.firebaseio.com"
});
```

and able to retrieve a data like this:

```
  var db = admin.database();
  var ref = db.ref("messages");

  ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  });
```

**But how can I check in NodeJS server whether user in client app has logged in** ? I need this NodeJS server to communicate with client and provide data and files if neccessary.

Answer (score 3):

Basically I solved an issue, following Firebase documentation:

> If your Firebase client app communicates with a custom backend server,
>   you might need to identify the currently signed-in user on that
>   server. To do so securely, after a successful sign-in, send the user's
>   ID token to your server using HTTPS. Then, on the server, verify the
>   integrity and authenticity of the ID token and retrieve the uid from
>   it. You can use the uid transmitted in this way to securely identify
>   the currently signed-in user on your server.

On my Facebook Login in Angular4 App:

```
loginFb() {

       this.loading = true;

       this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()).then(

        (user) => {

            console.log('loginFB');
            console.log(user);

            var token = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getToken().then(
            (token) => console.debug(`******** Token: ${token}`)); <== TOKEN

            this.af.object(`/users/${user.uid}`).update({
                displayName: user.auth.displayName,
                email: user.auth.email,
                photoURL: user.auth.photoURL
            });

            this.router.navigate(['/']);

          }).catch(
            (err) => {
            this.loading = false;
            this.error = err;
        });
    }
```

My NodeJS Server:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./server/service-account.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com"
});


...

//test method
router.get("/isAuth/:token", function (req, res) {

  var token = req.params.token;

  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
  .then(function(decodedToken) {

    var uid = decodedToken.uid;
    console.log(`Current User ID: ${uid}`);

    }).catch(function(error) {

    console.log("Error: " + error);
  });


});
```

This is how authentication can be checked.